# Retrieving the last record in each group - group by multiple columns

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, left-join

I'm doing a group of record with the same `post_id` and `sender id`, I want each group to return record with the lastest `time`, I'm using myql version 5, how do I do it.

This is my `messages` table

[image]

expected results:

[image]

I used the following query but it did not return the record with the lastest time in each group as my expectation

```
select * from `messages` group by `post_id`, `sender_id` order by `time` desc
```

Answer (score 0):

One method uses a correlated subquery:

```
select m.*
from messages m
where m.time = (select max(m2.time)
                from messages m2
                where (m2.post_id, m2.sender_id) in ( (m.post_id, m.sender_id), (m.sender_id, m.post_id))
               );
```